# I am trying to parameterized Sql query but I am getting the error"'Must declare the scalar variable "

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a parameter for all those values that is mentioned below in the code itself.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is what I did:

```
public static void Main()
    {

        {
            string testEnv = ClaimQuery.ClaimQueryhelper.getTestEnv();
            // calls claimQueryhelper for the test environment
            var connectionString = ClaimQuery.ClaimQueryhelper.getConnection(testEnv);
            // if we are not calling helper then the environment is hard coded
            //string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aitf"].ConnectionString;
            //ConsoleWindows.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = connectionString)
            {

                ///Sql to get the data from the Dbase
                string sql = "SELECT TOP 3 claim.CLCL_MICRO_ID,cdml.LOBD_ID,cdml.IDCD_ID,CLMD_TYPE, " +
                    "* FROM CMC_CLCL_CLAIM claim INNER JOIN CMC_CDML_CL_LINE cdml ON claim.CLCL_ID = cdml.CLCL_ID" +
                    " INNER JOIN CMC_CLMD_DIAG clmd ON claim.CLCL_ID = clmd.CLCL_ID WHERE CLCL_CUR_STS =@CLCL_CUR_STS AND @CLCL_CL_SUB_TYPE AND @CLCL_RECD_DT and @CLMD_TYPE ";

                //connecting to the Sql server
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                 //Reading the Sql database
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(
                        new[]
                            {
                             new SqlParameter(@"CLCL_CUR_STS", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "01",
                             new SqlParameter(@"CLCL_CL_SUB_TYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "M",
                              new SqlParameter(@"CLMD_TYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "01",
                              new SqlParameter(@"CLCL_RECD_DT", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "2017-02-03 00:00:00.000",
                             });
```

Comment: You are adding the parameter values *after* you have already executed the SQL via `ExecuteReader`.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Also did you try running the query directly against database from management studio?

Comment: This statement looks weird: `WHERE CLCL_CUR_STS =@CLCL_CUR_STS AND @CLCL_CL_SUB_TYPE AND @CLCL_RECD_DT and @CLMD_TYPE`. `AND` condition may evaluate to 'false' due to inequality: `WHERE CLCL_CUR_STS = '01' AND 'M' AND [datetime] AND '01'`

Answer (score 1):

The parameter values for `SqlCommand` query string (i.e. array of `SqlParameter`) must be iterated & assigned to the command before `DataReader` opens by using `ExecuteReader`. See this example below:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     // SQL query to get the data from the database
     string sql = @"[query string here]";
     con.Open();

     // connecting to the SQL Server
     using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
     {
         SqlParameter[] parameters = new[]
         {
             new SqlParameter(@"CLCL_CUR_STS", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "01",
             new SqlParameter(@"CLCL_CL_SUB_TYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "M",
             new SqlParameter(@"CLMD_TYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "01",
             new SqlParameter(@"CLCL_RECD_DT", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "2017-02-03 00:00:00.000",
         };

         foreach (SqlParameter sqlParam in parameters)
         {
             command.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
         }

         // Reading the SQL database
         using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
         {
             // fetch retrieved data
         }
     }

     // other stuff

     con.Close();
}
```

*Must declare the scalar variable* error obviously means that one or more of provided query parameters are not declared during query statement execution (they're wrongly declared after the `DataReader` has already open).

Comment: Thank you, I fixed my query declaring the parameter, which fixed my error